# How to identify process that generates data transfer out in EC2?

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am hosting a small web-based application with Apache Web Server on EC2. On my monthly fee I usually see ~40GB usage of data transfer out, which cause about $5 or so a month.

Although this is no big money, I am curious on how these data transfer out were generated. I am sure at Midnight there won't be anyone actually visiting the web-based application. And yet there are some data transfer out at ~50M per hour (as I can see from the details report from amazon).

Is there any way to figure out what process actually generates those data-transfer out activity (even at Midnight when no one uses the web-application)?

thanks!

J.

Comment: Presumably the first place to look would be the Apache web server access logs, which typically show the size of each request in bytes... unless of course you have a scheduled nightly backup that's sending the backup somewhere outside of EC2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you looked at [Boundary](http://boundary.com/), may be they can help.  They can monitor data going in and out of your EC2 instance (networking) You can see details like what ports the packets are coming from and where they are going to.

You have to install and agent on your machine and sign up for a trial.